# Is it posible to keep a gRPC server alive without using a sleep condition?

Tags: python, grpc

Please refer the below code:

```
import grpc

from concurrent import futures
import time

import calculator_pb2
import calculator_pb2_grpc
import calculator

class CalculatorServicer(calculator_pb2_grpc.CalculatorServicer):

    def SquareRoot(selfself, request, context):
        response = calculator_pb2.Number()
        response.value = calculator.square_root((request.value))
        return response

# Creating gRPC server
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))

calculator_pb2_grpc.add_CalculatorServicer_to_server(CalculatorServicer(), server)

print('Starting server. Listening on port 50051.')
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
server.start()

# The below line is what is keeping the server alive
try:
     while True:
         time.sleep(86400)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop(0)
```

#### **********************************

```
try:
     while True:
         time.sleep(86400)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop(0)
```

#### ***********************************

In the above code block, is it possible to not to using a sleep condition and still the server will be alive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently gRPC Python servers do not have an equivalent to the C++ server's `Wait()` API. You will need to keep the calls to Python's `time.sleep`, as in our [example server code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/f03344e73a4e0eafb969fe4675babcb50ac08ae6/examples/python/route_guide/route_guide_server.py#L123).

Comment: is there any plan in near future to add this?

Comment: Going forward this should be addressed with `await_for_termination()`: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/19299/files

Answer (score 0):

There is an experimental function you can use now : [wait_for_termination()](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.Server.wait_for_termination)

```
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
server.start()
server.wait_for_termination()
```

> Block current thread until the server stops.
>
> This is an EXPERIMENTAL API.
>
> The wait will not consume computational resources during blocking, and
> it will block until one of the two following conditions are met:
>
> 1. The server is stopped or terminated;
> 2. A timeout occurs if timeout is not None.